Change tab name using php when displaying a file/image
I'm currently creating a php page that receives an image from one API and shows that image (this php allows the user to define the image dimensions using GET methods).
I want that this php file displays the name of the image (or something I want to put there) on the tab. Is it possible just using php?
This is my current code:
$filename = "...";

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

//I tried this but this is just for download
// header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.png');

...

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$newwidth =  150;
$newheight = 150;
        
...

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);


// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        
// Output
imagepng($thumb);


This PHP script outputs an image and should only output an image, otherwise the image won't be valid. However, there's nothing stopping you writing another HTML/PHP script that includes the image, produced by the script in your question, using the <img> tag that adds the text you want.

@KIKOSoftware So it is not possible to do it with a single php file? For example editing the php.ini or something like that.
I'm asking because I've noticed that the php file is getting the last part of the url to define the tab name.

What is the problem with having 2 scripts? You use one script to get the image from the API, resize it, and output it. The second script you use to render the HTML for your webpage, which includes an <img> tag to the first script. It might be possible to use one script if you don't resize the image, but I can't tell from your question. Note that there's a difference between resizing the image in the image file itself, and setting the size at which the image is being displayed.

Side-note: you are telling the browser that you're sending it a JPEG (Content-Type: image/jpg) but actually sending a PNG (imagepng). The browser will probably be smart enough to render it anyway, but to be sure, you should send the correct header (Content-Type: image/png)

Another side-note: The term "tab" is ambiguous. It could be a browser tab, the way IMSoP read it, or it could be a HTML tab. It could even be a single character.

Have you tried header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.png');

@KIKOSoftware I thought about that but I was unsure... my main idea is to give to the main website a "masked image url", i.e, instead of giving the image url, I'm creating a PHP that receives a hash key, expected width/height and image ID and then returns the corresponding image resized.
The browser tab is just a simple detail I wanted to put if some user goes directly to the "generated image" url.

@IMSoP I've noticed that before, however I left the jpg return since I'm going to change imagens from png to jpg on final version

@RuiOliveira In that case, you should correct it to image/jpeg, which is the official media type for that format. Abbreviating to "JPG" instead of "JPEG" comes from 1990s file systems which only allocated three characters for the file type extension, and isn't applicable in this context.

PHP does not have direct control of the browser. In fact, the browser doesn't know that PHP even exists.
The way HTTP works, from the browser's point of view is this:

You enter a URL in your browser's address bar, or click a link, e.g. https://example.com/foo/bar?a=1#bar
The browser looks at the first part of the URL, between https:// and the next / and connects to whatever server it sees there (e.g. example.com)
Then it looks at the rest of the URL (or everything up to the # sign, if there is one), and sends a request to the server, e.g. GET /foo/bar/?a=1
The server replies with some headers, and the body data. The body data is basically a file you're transmitting; it doesn't have any HTTP-specific bits, those are all in the headers.
The browser then has to interpret that and decide what to display. The most important header is Content-Type, which tells the browser if the body data is an HTML page, a JPEG image, a PDF, etc.

From PHP's point of view, everything happens between steps 3 and 4:

The server receives a request, e.g. GET /foo/bar/?a=1
Some PHP code runs, and outputs some headers and some data
The end.

Hopefully this explains why there can't be any PHP-specific way to change the title of a browser tab. There are only two things that could influence it:

The HTTP response headers
The data, which is in a particular file format

To my knowledge, there is no HTTP header for specifying a browser tab title. If you're outputting an HTML page, you can use the <title> tag in the response body. But a JPEG or PNG file doesn't have a "title", so there is nowhere you can output that.
You could however generate an HTML page, and within that page have an <img> tag pointing to the actual image.

I understand all of that, however, since PHP is server-side, and you can define some parameters, such as content-type, I was hoping that I was able to change some sort of "content-title" parameter to give a natural feel to the php page.
As I explained earlier, this php page is to resize and somehow mask with a token the image access. However, I wanted to change the browser tab title accordingly to the image, to give a more natural look.

@RuiOliveira Now that I understand that you want to set the browser tab title I know a solution. Have a look again at the comment above by Ultimater. The browser tab title should reflect whatever you set as the filename.

@RuiOliveira I address that directly: "Content-Type" is an HTTP Header, and "To my knowledge, there is no HTTP header for specifying a browser tab title."

@KIKOSoftware If you think you have an answer, post it as one; don't hide it in comment sections.

@KIKOSoftware I already explored Ultimater option but I forgot to answer him.. That solution is not working either

@IMSoP I think that you're right, that's why I marked your answer as "accepted".
